# display Processing .pde file in Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby, rubygems, processing, processing.js

I am fairly new to Ruby as well as Processing, but I have a page built in Ruby and would like to know how to display my Processing .PDE files on that Page.  I have read online that you need Processing.js

i have copied the code for processing.js from [processingjs.org][1] and put it in a file called processing.js in app/assets/javascripts

I have saved a .pde file called butters.pde in app/assets/images/data.

Am I calling the script correctly in the header and the file correctly in the body?  I'm not seeing anything when I try to view the page.

```
<head>
  <title>Hello</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <script src="assets/javascripts/processing.js"></script>
</head>
```

and

```
<body>
    <canvas data-processing-sources="/assets/images/data/butters.pde"></canvas>
</body>
```

The Terminal reads:

```
Started GET "/assets/images/data/butters.pde" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-23 14:55:18 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/data/butters.pde"):
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
```

The browser console reads:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   http://localhost:3000/assest/javascripts/processing.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  http://localhost:3000/assets/images/data/butters.pde
Uncaught Processing.js: Unable to load pjs sketch files: /assets/images/data/butters.pde ==> Invalid XHR status 404
```

Comment: sorry about that.  thanks for the tips.  edited question.

Comment: really? processing 1.0.0? The current version is 1.4.8, 1.0.0 is several *years* olds. That said, check your browser's dev tools console and see whether it's hitting a 404 or the link. Good chance you're trying to resolve the file from the wrong dir.

Comment: yes, processing 1.0.0 is the only processing.js ruby gem that I could find.  I realize its very old, but I don't know what else to do.  I was going by the only tutorial I could find at http://processingjs.org/articles/p5QuickStart.html#quickstart.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: don't use the gem installer, just grab processing.js from the website, add it as a normal script in the `<head>` and then if you generate a page with a `<canvas data-processing-sources="file1.pde file2.pde ..."></canvas>` it'll automatically load them on page ready.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have edited my question - not using gem installer anymore, am trying to do it with processing.js from the website but i'm not getting it...does anything look wrong with the updated code? thanks.

Comment: what does the browser console say? Good bet it's a 404 if it's not loading the way you have it right now.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks again for the help so far, I posted what console is telling me, the browser isn't showing me anything.  Do I need a route for the file in the config/routes.rb like with a page?

Comment: that's not the browser console, that's your terminal. In firefox or chrome open the dev tools and look at what the page reports in the "console", and "network" tabs. Although that "routing error" certainly looks like you're trying to fetch a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Oh whoops, yes I am getting 404 errors in the browser console, I have edited the question to show the errors

Comment: that's actually all the information you need to solve the problem yourself. You're asking for the files in the wrong place, simply fix that.